# Parse dynamic XML

Tags: xml, parsing, go, struct

I understand how to unmarshal simple xml data to Go structs but can't figure out how to handle dynamic tags. Here's an example. There can be `<image_3><image_4>` etc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
  <product>
    <product_id>11600</product_id>
    <date_created><![CDATA[2018-10-19 15:20:22]]></date_created>
    <price>200</price>
    <stock_status>In Stock</stock_status>
    <images>
      <image_1>1.jpg</image_1>
      <image_2>2.jpg</image_2>
   </images
   </product>
</products>
```

//update

```
type Products struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:"products"`
        Text    string   `xml:",chardata"`
        Product struct {
                Text        string `xml:",chardata"`
                ProductID   string `xml:"product_id"`
                DateCreated string `xml:"date_created"`
                Price       string `xml:"price"`
                StockStatus string `xml:"stock_status"`
                Images          map[string]string `xml:"images"`
        } `xml:"product"`
}
```

When I run `fmt.Println(len(products.Product[0].Images))` I get 0. What I'm missing here?

Comment: You can implement the xml.Unmarshaler interface on a custom map type like so: https://play.golang.com/p/gi9Fiv3PS8M

Comment: Is this XML under your control? Because dynamic tags are a VERY bad practice.

Comment: Unfortunately the xml file is a 3rd party

Comment: @mkopriva your suggestion works like a charm. Please add it as a answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the xml.Unmarshaler interface on a custom map type like so:

```
type Images map[string]string

func (i *Images) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    *i = make(Images) // initialize the map
    for {
        tok, err := d.Token()
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                return nil
            }
            return err
        }

        if se, ok := tok.(xml.StartElement); ok {
            tok, err = d.Token()
            if err != nil {
                if err == io.EOF {
                    return nil
                }
                return err
            }
            if data, ok := tok.(xml.CharData); ok {
                (*i)[se.Name.Local] = string(data)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/gi9Fiv3PS8M

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library (https://github.com/clbanning/mxj):

```
var input = []byte(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <products>
        <product>
            <name>hello</name>
            <images>
                <image1>one</image1>
                <image2>one</image2>
            </images>
        </product>
    </products>`)

type Products struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"products"`
    Products []Product `xml:"product"`
}

type Product struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"product"`
    Name string `xml:"name"`
    Images map[string]interface{}
}


func (p *Product) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {

    var v struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:"product"`
        Name string `xml:"name"`
        Images struct {
            Inner []byte `xml:",innerxml"`
        } `xml:"images"`
    }

    err := d.DecodeElement(&v, &start)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    images := make(map[string]interface{})
    // use mxj here and fill images from v.Images.Inner

    p.Name = v.Name
    p.Images = images

    return nil
}


func main() {

    var data Products
    err := xml.Unmarshal(input, &data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```